# changes to subsetting within tibble package; new error for previously working code

Tags: r, tibble

**The code below creates raw data similar to what I am working with. I wrote some code to reformat it using the add_row function in the tibble package. Now I'm getting an error (this code worked this past April 2020). It looks like the rules for subsetting have gotten stricter due to an update to the package? I'm wondering if anyone can help rectify this error...
First create the data**

```
# Create replicate of raw data
date <- seq(from = as.Date('1999-01-01'),
            to = as.Date('2013-12-31'),
            by = 'day')

temp <- rnorm(5479,15,5)

precip <- rlnorm(5479)

rawdata <- data.frame(date=date,
                      temp=round(temp, digits = 2),
                      precip=round(precip, digits = 2))
# Add columns needed to run code
rawdata$year <- as.numeric(substr(rawdata$date,1,4))
rawdata$month <- as.numeric(substr(rawdata$date, 6,7))
rawdata$chardate <- format(rawdata$date, '%Y-%h-%d') # create abbreviated month column
rawdata$charmonth <- substr(rawdata$chardate, 6,8)   # for formatting
rawdata$charmonth <- as.character(rawdata$charmonth)
rawdata$day <- as.numeric(substr(rawdata$date, 9,10))
rawdata$uniqdate <- rawdata$year*100+as.numeric(rawdata$day)+rawdata$month*10 
rawdata$uniqmonth <- (rawdata$year*100)+rawdata$month# create unique month identifier
rawdata$yr <- NA # This column will be filled only in the new rows to be added

# Create weather object to feed the for loop below----
weather <- data.frame(year = rawdata$year, 
                      month = rawdata$month, 
                      day = rawdata$day,
                      charmonth = rawdata$charmonth,
                      uniqmonth = rawdata$uniqmonth, 
                      uniqdate = rawdata$uniqdate, 
                      temp = rawdata$temp, 
                      precip = rawdata$precip, 
                      yr = rawdata$yr)

# weather$charmonth <- as.character(rawdata$charmonth)
```

**Now the error...I'm trying to add a row at the top of each month of data containing the number of days in the month, a three letter month abbreviated (jan, feb, mar etc.), and the year.**

```
library(tibble) # package containing the add_row function
# create empty list to put all of the monthly dataframes in
newdat <- list() 

# the following loop will  create a dataframe for each month and put in a list
for(i in unique(weather$uniqmonth)) { # for every unique month value
  # create object nam that is of the format 'df.uniqmonth'
  nam <- paste("df", i, sep = ".")    
  # create object dat that contains all data for each unique month
  dat <- weather[weather$uniqmonth==i,]
  # add a row of data at the start of each dataframe with the days in month, month abbr., year
  dat <- add_row(dat, year = NA, month = NA, day = NA, 
                 charmonth = NA, uniqmonth = NA, uniqdate = NA, 
                 # the line below is the info we are adding in the columns we will keep
                 temp = na.omit(max(dat$day)), precip = unique(dat$charmonth), yr = unique(dat$year),
                 .before = 1)
  # just keep required columns
  dat <- data.frame(dat$temp, dat$precip, dat$yr) 
  # add new dataframe to a list, using the new name
  newdat[[nam]] <- dat 
}
```

****You can run the loop or just go line by line (set i = 199901) and the error is the same:**

*Error: Can't combine `..1$precip`  and `..2$precip` .*

**Ultimately I should be able to run the following to get the output I need which I finalize in a text editor (remove trailing commas).****

```
# Merge all data into a dataframe
full_data <- do.call("rbind", newdat)

# turn NA's into blanks
full_data[is.na(full_data)] <- ""
```

**I appreciate any help solving this error!

Here is what I need as the final product

```
a <- c("Jan", 
       round(rnorm(31,15,5), digits = 2),
       "Feb",
       round(rnorm(28,5,5), digits = 2),
       "Mar",
       round(rnorm(31,15,5),digits = 2))
b <- c(31, 
       rlnorm(31),
       28,
       rlnorm(28),
       31,
       rlnorm(31))
c <- c(1999, 
       rep(NA,31),
       1999,
       rep(NA,28),
       1999,
       rep(NA,31))

final_data <- data.frame(temp = a,
                         precip = round(b,digits=2), 
                         year = c)
```

Comment: I don't understand why adding a row with `precip=unique(dat$charmonth)` (of class `character`) would be appendable to `dat$precip` which is of class `numeric`.

Comment: Frankly, I get a different (but equally avoidable) error when `i <- 1`.

Comment: I started working on this, but I fear I'm inferring waaaaay too much. What I don't understand is why you'd assign `max(dat$day)` to `temp`, and `unique(date$charmonth)` to `precip`. If that is intentional, then ... I have no idea how to help you other than suggest you convert everything to a string and hope that downstream uses of the data can adapt. (No, that's not a real suggestion, but the code as it stands makes no sense to me.)

Comment: Additionally, your use of adding "a row" using `unique` in there suggests that you intend to produce `n` rows. This *assumes* that all of your `unique` calls will produce the same length (or 1), otherwise you'll either get recycling (which is a data-corruption problem) or an error (which should really be the default behavior with non-1-recycling). I suspect that this can all be done with a simple `weather %>% group_by(uniqmonth) %>% summarize(...) %>% bind_rows(weather)` (instead of a `for` loop and `rbind`ing later), but the problems with the code have me flummoxed.

Comment: (Lastly, your `full_data[is.na(full_data)] <- ""` is really doing what I jokingly suggested two comments ago: it will convert all fields (that contain at least one `NA`) to `character`.)

Comment: @r2evans  I'm going to try to answer your inquiries and provide you enough background without boring you with the minutia of why I need the data to be formatted in such an odd way. This is a means to an end for me. The "full_data" object is what I print to a .txt file and edit in a text editor to trim trailing commas (couldn't figure out how to do so in R) and then I use it in a watershed model input file. The strange formatting is what is required by the model. So ultimately I don't care whether the data is a character or numeric because I'm translating it all upon export into the .txt file.

Comment: @ r2evans The reason for using max(dat$day) and unique(dat$charmonth) is because of the formatting that I need in the output. I need to add a row holds 1: the number of days in the month aka max(dat$day) because dat only holds the specific month I am referencing (hence the use of the uniquemonth identifier), 2: The three letter month abbreviation aka unique(dat$charmonth), and 3: the year aka unique(dat$year).

Comment: @ r2evans I only intend to introduce one row into each "dat" data object which is included the the "full_data" object when I rbind later on (so at the top of each month is a row with the three values in my previous comment). The use of full_data[is.na(full_data) <-"" is simply to remove all the excess "fat" so to speak (the data that I don't need in the final product) and be left with only the data of interest. Even though I end up with numeric values defined as characters it doesn't affect my desired outcome to print to a .txt file and use external to R

Comment: I should add that this worked fine for me prior to this week. I've run this code using multiple datasets over 3 months this past spring to the desired effect

Comment: “Can’t combine” means that vctrs can’t combine double and character vectors. fromhttps://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/04/dplyr-1-0-0-and-vctrs/

Comment: You say you need the max number of days in the month, then ... why do you store that in `temp`??

Comment: If you say that the output is supposed to have `charmonth` in it, then why are you assigning `NA`? The trailing comma on each line is because your last column `yr` is completely blank. The problem is *not* that your CSV has a trailing comma, it's that your last comma is completely *empty* (aka null aka `NA`), and R's default for `NA` values is to write them as an empty string `""` (and without quotes).

Comment: You are absolutely correct! And it's just the way it is! The folks who built this watershed model decided that was the best way to format the input data....in reality I remove the column names before entering the data into this input file. So long story short I'm looking for a workaround so that I can create "full_data" as define, NA's, trailing commas and all. The previous version of tibble allowed this. But since an update the functionality has become stricter as per the link in my last comment. Thanks for trying I appreciate it

Comment: ok, I get it, you are frustrated by this, I am confused with column names being interchanged. Perhaps you can include just one `uniqmonth`'s worth of `dat` given this sample data?

Comment: I understand the confusion, it's a horribly weird way to structure things. I'm confused by your last comment though. The reason I structured ```weather``` the way I did is because that's exactly what I'm dealing with in my actual data. So only using one month of data won't help? I apologize if I'm misunderstanding

Comment: No, you provided `weather`. I'm asking that you provide one month's worth of `dat.` I tried a couple of months and repeatedly get errors, so I would like to *verify* what you think the final output should be. This is likely *after* you create 9 columns and immediately discard 6 of them. It's mostly for verification, I suspect this process and be a bit more efficient (and perhaps less confusing to me).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220645/discussion-between-r2evans-and-dandrews).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long discussion, the end result is not a traditional CSV, so it takes a little *bending*.

Given that `weather` starts looking like this:

```r
head(weather)
# # A tibble: 6 x 9
#    year month   day charmonth uniqmonth uniqdate  temp precip yr   
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <lgl>
# 1  1999     1     1 Jan          199901   199911 13.8    2.03 NA   
# 2  1999     1     2 Jan          199901   199912 10.8    2.53 NA   
# 3  1999     1     3 Jan          199901   199913  8.78   3.15 NA   
# 4  1999     1     4 Jan          199901   199914 14.3    0.63 NA   
# 5  1999     1     5 Jan          199901   199915 18.5    0.47 NA   
# 6  1999     1     6 Jan          199901   199916 10.4    0.39 NA
```

the desired output (`full_data`) is something like this in the file:

```
Jan,31,1999
13.83,2.03
10.76,2.53
8.78,3.15
...truncated...
18.74,0.79
Feb,28,1999
17.47,1.62
9.15,0.48
...truncated...
18.36,2.26
Mar,31,1999
20.53,2.65
11.1,2.58
19.52,0.33
...truncated...
```

The point being that the output is effectively two columns: `precip` and `temp`, but every "day" there needs to be a 3-column header of sorts.

I think the easiest way to deal with this is to first `group_by` the main grouping variable (`uniqmonth`) and then `do` something with each group of data. This "something" is effectively: (1) create the new header row, which is `charmonth,max(day)` and `year`. Since that has one more comma than we want in the normal CSV, I'll embed a comma into the first field and tell `write.table` to not quote it. It's a workaround, but ... it works.

```r
library(dplyr)
weather %>%
  group_by(uniqmonth) %>%
  do({
    bind_rows(
      tibble(temp = paste(.$charmonth[1], max(.$day), sep = ","),
             precip = as.character(.$year[1])),
      mutate_all(select(., temp, precip), as.character)
    )
  }) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-uniqmonth) %>%
  write.table(., file = "quux.csv", quote = FALSE,
              sep = ",", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```